# Are wrong variable names and other simple rookie mistakes (0 effort questions) flagable?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

If so, which flags am I supposed to use? I think those type of questions don't add anything to the site, especially if those mistakes are embedded in lengthy programs and their title are going to harm future searches of people.

I think they have been flaggable at some point in the past, but at some point the flag system was reordered/reworked or I simply have forgotten which flag is the right one.

Comment: Thanks, I've been confused by meta tags since the beginning of time. I thought support is for questions to the develop team specificially.

Comment: I really wish that I could just edit the tags myself and get progress towards Explainer/Refiner/Illuminator.

Comment: It's weird that you aren't allowed to even suggest edits on meta. Never noticed. I mean even without a review queue the OP still could accept them.

Comment: There still is a Suggested Edits queue on Meta—it's just that it's only used for tag wiki edits.

Comment: "Simple rookie mistake" could use some disambiguation, possibly some examples.

Answer (score 7):

Under Close => Off-topic:

> This question was caused by a problem that can **no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Well, yes if they are really typographical errors. But what if the person just swapped car with pencil and wrote a line of code not making any sense. Does this count aswell?

Comment: 1: that would be a typographical error. 2: that's more of a job for downvoting.